# why the bake result in green

Tags: baking

With all the face pointing outside in correct direction. Still the bake result giving a green result.

[image]

[image]

Any suggestion or help why the result is in green. Thanks

Comment: It looks like the top face of your low poly shares the exact same space as your high poly (too close -believe it or not). Try either scaling one or the other up or down very slightly (around .001, give or take), or move the top edge of the high poly up on the z by around the same amount and bake again. It should clean things up a little, but I think more work needs to be done to properly incorporate the "bolts".

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to do, actually in your current file you are trying to bake the lowpoly object with the highpoly, don't you want to do the opposite?